# Rails: Reconnecting to sqlite3 DB when underlying .sqlite3 file changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sqlite

**The situation:**

I have a Rails 3.1.3 app running which loads a sqlite3 DB and queries it. Standard stuff.
It runs inside an apache with phusion passenger.
Versions are sqlite3 (GEM/1.3.5), ruby 1.9.3-p0, sqlite3 (libs/bin) 3.6.12

**The problem:**

The sqlite3 file is loaded from a directory that resides outside of the Rails App root and **can be updated via a separate (SVN) process**

What I want to do is reload the file every five minutes (which is easy).
But how can I reconnect the DB (file) after five minutes in Rails?

**What I tried:**

Inside my_model.rb:

```
if time_to_reload
  self.connection.reconnect!
  self.establish_connection
end
```

or

```
if time_to_reload
  self.connection.disconnect!
  self.connection.reconnect!
end
```

I tried nearly all permutations of those, no success so far.

I get `SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked` or `prepare called on a closed database`

Is there a failsafe way to force a reconnect to the file, closing and reopening all file handles?

Thanks,
Frank

As a sidenote:

```
1.9.3-p0-perf :006 > MyModel.connection.disconnect!
 => #<SQLite3::Database:0x0000010474f220> 
1.9.3-p0-perf :007 > MyModel.connected?
 => true 
1.9.3-p0-perf :008 > WAT?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!
```

works

But it disconnects all databases ...